# Can university revoke the degree when data were edited/fabricated? Is student or supervisor at fault? Can the student be sent to prison or fined?

Tags: thesis

Say a M. Tech thesis contains original experimental data, but some results were edited to show significant results, and is this is later found out. Can this editing result in a cancelling/revocation of the awarded degree, even if found after some years? Who can be held responsible for this fabrication (faculty, student, and/or supervisor)? What action will/can the university take on the student? Can the student be punished legally with prison and/or fine?

Comment: The "prison or fine" part will depend on what your country's laws say.  You haven't said what country that is, but I think that part is not really on-topic for this site.  (Though I don't know any country where prison or fine are possible for falsifying results in a thesis.  In grant-supported research, maybe, but still unlikely.)

Comment: **Don't do it.**

Comment: It will depend on who does the fabricating.  If the student fabricates data and the supervisor/faculty doesn't know, then they are not complicit.  If the thesis is only for school, prison is not likely; if it is part of a grant for developing a new drug, then prison might be an option.

Comment: the fabrication is only in answer. the experimental data is original. supervisor also know about it. fabrication is for making significant result. not related with drug, it is related with machining and cant harm anyone.is only student fault or supervisor. can court can take any major action on student

Comment: This is typically handled by the university and not the court. But you could loose your degree anytime, and that can have consequences for your employment. Often it only ends in court if you choose to appeal against the university's decision

Comment: if the previous results are also satisfactory but supervisor say for change some results for making results significant. the student is work according to the supervisor and dont know what is right and wrong. if thesis found wrong after award of degree, can university evaluate this and announce it OK and how the fault in thesis found later.

Answer (score 5):

A prominent German example is former minister of defence zu Gutenberg. He lost his title *and* his job because of plagiarism years after the fact.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl-Theodor_zu_Guttenberg

However, this may very well work differently in other countries.

Comment: To underline Mr. zu Guttenberg is not just a one-off case, please also list his colleague [Annette Schavan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annette_Schavan), or some other cases from [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VroniPlag_Wiki#Current_cases).

Comment: Question is about fabricating data, not plagiarism.

Comment: True, but in terms of severity I would say they are comparable.

Comment: I'd say that fabricating data is ten times worse. If the contents of a paper is good and correct then I can learn from it, whether it's plagiarised or not. If a paper contains fabricated data and I read it, then it is actively hurting me because I learn things that are not true.

Comment: I disagree: Plagiarism undermines the very process through which academia works. Regardless, I think we can agree that both are very bad practices.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It happens and it can change national elections.

In 2013, US Senator [Max Baucus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Baucus) (D-MT) was retiring.  Incumbency is always an advantage, so when Baucus retired early, [John Walsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Walsh_(U.S._politician)) was appointed to fill his seat shortly before the election.

But then the New York Times published [devastating evidence](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/07/25/us/politics/plagiarism-raises-ethical-alarm-at-military-school.html) that Walsh had plagiarized his thesis for a master's degree at the US Army War College years earlier.  The War College revoked his degree and ground his name off a bronze plaque bearing the names of his graduating class.

Walsh was forced to withdraw his candidacy and his was one of the seats Republicans gained in that election.

It was later revealed that the source of the information was a researcher on staff with the National Republican Senatorial Committee.

Comment: Question is about fabricating data, not plagiarism.

Comment: @MikeP, academic misconduct is academic misconduct.  Take your pick of how you do it, but if you're caught, this is what can happen.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins, yes, thank you for catching that, now corrected.